# How to replace char in file with appropriate ascii code in vim

Tags: vim

In a vim buffer if I have a list of characters say:

A

B

c

C

d

D

and for each one I want to replace it with its corresponding ascii code ( in decimal ).  Is there a way to do this without using an external tool through :r!some_tool

For instance, I know there is the :ascii and ga commands but they print the value to the screen but I can't find a way to get its output into the buffer.

Comment: This looks more like a superuser.com question.

Comment: Never heard of superuser.com ... Reading the faq on both stackoverflow and superuser still leaves me unsure where is the right place to ask it.  However, I posted it there and appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to ask this question here (on stackoverflow) because 1) vim is an IDE for many and 2) the solution to this problem might entail some coding.

Comment: Thank kind of "problem" as been evoked there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/allow-cross-posting-of-questions-to-more-than-one-so-site/25155#25155 The reactions make me think that SO should host no vim questions at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [sub-replace-expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression) functionality along with [char2nr()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#char2nr()) and [submatch()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#submatch()).  The following replaces any alphabetic character at the start of the line with its decimal equivalent.

```
%s/^\a/\=char2nr(submatch(0))/
```

If you want to do this for any character at the start of the line, simply replace the `\a` with `.`.